# Vector space and Field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why is it that we call the elements of a vector space to be  vectors and that of a field to be scalars?? or if I am wrong at what I am telling please to correct it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Elements of the field *scale* the vectors (multiply them)

Comment: The terminology comes from the canonical examples of vector spaces: $\mathbb R^n$.